# Relevance of questions about older versions of software

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This was asked before, "Retiring old questions" but its not really an old question, however, the relevance of questions for current MSBuild is being diluted with questions that pertain to older versions of MSBuild but without much indication of that.

For instance, I ran across an old MSBuild question that only applies for v10 but not for MSBuild current.

Should the question tagging system be enhanced to support specific versions?

Comment: Didn't you mean to ask this at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: @AlE. no: "Should the question tagging system be enhanced to support specific versions?" That is general stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tags with version numbers, like [c#-6](/questions/tagged/c%23-6) for example. Those tags warrant a separate tag for there high amount of questions *and* questions specific to that version (like enhancements in version B over A). So there is no need for the tag system to change: everything is there already.

If the [msbuild](/questions/tagged/msbuild) tag should be split is a matter of the per-site meta, in this case Meta Stack Overflow, but in general, there is nothing against it. I would suggest to make a case there and let the community decide.

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone right now is talking about the main site, I would like to leave here some notices about different realities.
We have the same problem at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com. Over the course of years, version tags were created to handle situations where an answer was actually specific to a single SharePoint version. This caused many discussions to arise, which are well summarized in this post by Jeff.

[Version tags considered harmful](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/version-tags-considered-harmful)

While some of the point do not make sense when applied to larger scopes, it is worth to keep in mind at least some point (note: original list by Jeff)

> 3. Version tags make questions disposable. The entire point of Stack Exchange is for questions to be editable, timeless resources -- a version tag implies exactly the opposite and ties questions to specific moments in time, with no incentive to improve them to be relevant to future versions. This is extremely dangerous!
> 4. Version tags encourage needless question duplication. Rather than "How do I do X?" which can cover both supported versions, now there has to be "How do I do X in Version 1?" and "How do I do X in Version 2?"

Yes, I know - many will actually disagree, as many disagreed back then. But that is not the point.

Let's then move to what Shog9 had to say.

[A philosophy of tagging](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/a/152/5173)

> This is probably the best argument against version-specific tags. If you're used to answering SharePoint 2007 questions and browse the site looking for that tag, you're going to miss any question that isn't specific to that version. By assuming most questions are version-specific, you resign yourself to a future where all questions are version-specific! No matter how good your intentions might be regarding cross-version duplicates, you're setting yourself up for failure by creating a site where users are encouraged to ignore a giant chunk of the questions.

and [Kit Menke answer too](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/a/145/5173)

> 2. Version tags are a crutch encourage users to give their question helpful context. People are using the tags which is great. In order to answer the question accurately, the answerer needs as much information as possible. I do understand your point about users tagging a question with only the version tag. However, instead of discouraging the version tag we should encourage adding more than one tag. What if we made the minimum number of required tags TWO instead of one?
> 3. Version tags do not make questions disposable. Just because the version tag is present doesn't mean the question is disposable or doesn't provide value to someone searching for a different version. Additionally, we already decided that duplicate questions would be closed. This would encourage (or force) users to post relevant information in older posts. Once additional information is added, we can always retag the question if needed.

As you can see, sadly there isn't a real silver bullet to the "version specific question/answer" problem. The issue surely exist and many opposing view have been implemented and taken in account across the network. What make sense for a site may actually be useless for another: just think at the importance of specifying versions when talking about D&D ruling and how versions don't even make sense for sites like Travel or Cooking (now, meet Chocolate Pudding v.2.1.5).

In the end I think that each community will have to decide for itself, taking Shog and Jeff original guidelines into account while discussing the solution that is more appropriate for the specific case.

Comment: "The entire point of Stack Exchange is for questions to be editable, timeless resources -- a version tag implies exactly the opposite and ties questions to specific moments in time"  /this is not an accurate analogy./ Questions/answers that are relevant for Version1 behavior are often incorrect and/or false for a that behavior that has been upgraded/fixed for Version2.  We aren't tying to specific moments in time, but to specific versions of software that have a finite lifetime.

Comment: in relation to my above comment, I'm not digging into the version being in the tag, but perhaps the question itself includes meta-data for the OP to include the specific version that is exhibiting behavior/warranted a question